# Extract data from 2d array java

Tags: java, arrays

How can i extract data from a 2d array.. e and b are indexes of the array

```
int e = IO.readInt();

        int b = IO.readInt();

        int a[][] = { { 8, 2, 6, 5 }, // row 0
                { 6, 3, 1, 0 }, // row 1
                { 8, 7, 9, 6 } };

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {

                a[i][j] = i;

                System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }`enter code here`
```

Comment: What should the extracted data look like ?

Comment: What does your code do? How does that differ from what you wanted it to do?

Comment: You haven't really asked a question here, but whatever you're trying to do, this: `a[i][j] = i;` doesn't seem helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of a 2D array like a table. If you visualize it this way, your array `a[]` would look like this:

```
8 2 6 5
6 3 1 0
8 7 9 6
```

Then to access the elements in the array, you have to provide the row number and the column number:

```
    0 1 2 3
   --------
0 | 8 2 6 5
1 | 6 3 1 0
2 | 8 7 9 6
```

So, for example, in row 0, column 3 is the number 5. In code this would look like `a[0][3]`.

Technically speaking, a 2D array is actually an array of arrays, but it's often easier to think of it as a table.

Comment: What if you wanted to pull more than piece of info out of a 2d array? like `a[0][1-3]`?

Answer (score 3):

More details would be nice but I'll take a stab (in the dark) at it ...

```
a[e][b]
```